# ORACLE SQL "print"-keyword as column name

Tags: sql, oracle, overriding, naming

I have a problem with my Oracle SQL query. It requires naming a column "PRINT" to override a value that was selected by selecting ' * '.

```
'TRUE' AS "PRINT"
```

The column should override the oririnal content of the "PRINT" colum that is included in

```
select *
```

Unfortunately, "PRINT" is recognised as a keyword (either by Oracle or my DBMS) and so in the resulting output table there is the original "PRINT" column, which is still 'FALSE', and a new column named "PRINT_1" which is the selected constant 'TRUE'.

As you can see, I already used "as" and double quotes in order to try to escape the keyword but somehow it's not working as I thought it would. So how do I do that?

As requested the query:

```
SELECT H.*
, 'TRUE' as "PRINT"
FROM TABLE H
```

Comment: Please paste your query

Comment: What are the columns in table H?  There is something else going on with H.*, because if I execute "select 'TRUE' as"PRINT" from dual", it comes out correctly.  ALso show the output of your query in its entirety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `print` being a keyword (it isn't, by the way, though it is a SQL*Plus command).  The problem is that adding an additional column to your projection (the set of columns in your `SELECT` list) will never "overwrite" another column in the projection even if you try to name them the same.  If you want to force the value of `PRINT` to be `'TRUE'`, you'd need to explicitly list the columns that you want (other than `PRINT`) and then add your computed `PRINT` column.

In other words

```
SELECT h.col1, h.col2, h.col3, ... h.colN,
       'TRUE' as print
  FROM table_name h
```

where `col1` - `colN` omits the `PRINT` column

Comment: That's it. The reason for me not trying it is the almost infinite number of columns in this table that I didn't want to add manually. Did it now and works like a charm.